# Javascript nameof object property

Tags: javascript, typescript

In C# there is the posibility to get the name of an object property as a string value.

nameof(object.myProperty) --> "myProprty"

Can this be done in Javascript/Typescript?

Object.Keys() is the only thing i found, but it gives me all the keys.

Example what I want to achieve:

```
export interface myObject {
     myProperty: string;
}

console.log(myObject["myProperty"]);
```

Let's say I change my interface for some reason to:

```
export interface myObject {
     myPropertyOther: string;
}

console.log(myObject["myProperty"]); // This will not give an error on build
```

So I want to have something like this:

```
console.log(myObject[nameOf(myObject.myProperty)]
// This will give an error on build when the interface is changed
```

Comment: https://schneidenbach.gitbooks.io/typescript-cookbook/nameof-operator.html

Comment: dont you have to know the name of the key to get the key?

Comment: I know the name of the property. When I make changes, it will give an error on the property, but the key is a string value and will not give an error

Comment: You already have the name of the property. That's how you access this property in an object—by its name. The question seems very odd to me to be honest.

Comment: @series0ne that's just perfect

Comment: @Linnot - So based on that link, what you want **isn't** to know the name of the property. What you want is an error if the name you have isn't a valid property name for a given type. That's a very, very different thing. (And that link's `nameof` is a terrible name for it. More like `assertValidName`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `nameof` operator in Javascript/Typescript. You can creat a function that takes the key of another object and this is checked by the typescript compiler:

```
function keyOf<T>(o: T, k: keyof T) {
    return k
}

let o = { a: 1 }
keyOf(o, 'a'); //ok
keyOf(o, 'b'); //err
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a library that fetches the name of a property at runtime, even for types that don't exist at runtime (interfaces or types in TypeScript):

It can be found on NPM here: [@fluffy-spoon/name-of](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/name-of)

The source code is simple (just a few lines of code): https://github.com/ffMathy/FluffySpoon.JavaScript.NameOf

## Usage

```js
import { getPropertyName, getDeepPropertyName } from '@fluffy-spoon/name-of';

interface SomeType {
  foo: boolean;

  someNestedObject: {
      bar: string;
  }
}

console.log(getPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.foo)); //prints "foo"
console.log(getPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.someNestedObject)); //prints "someNestedObject"
console.log(getPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.someNestedObject.bar)); //prints "bar"

console.log(getDeepPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.foo)); //prints "foo"
console.log(getDeepPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.someNestedObject)); //prints "someNestedObject"
console.log(getDeepPropertyName<SomeType>(x => x.someNestedObject.bar)); //prints "someNestedObject.bar"
```

## Library source code

In case you don't want to install the NPM package.

```js
function getPropertyNameInternal<T = unknown>(expression: (instance: T) => any, options: {
    isDeep: boolean
}) {
    let propertyThatWasAccessed = "";
    var proxy: any = new Proxy({} as any, {
        get: function(_: any, prop: any) {
            if(options.isDeep) {
                if(propertyThatWasAccessed)
                    propertyThatWasAccessed += ".";
                
                propertyThatWasAccessed += prop;
            } else {
                propertyThatWasAccessed = prop;
            }
            return proxy;
        }
    });
    expression(proxy);

    return propertyThatWasAccessed;
}

export function getPropertyName<T = unknown>(expression: (instance: T) => any) {
    return getPropertyNameInternal(expression, {
        isDeep: false
    });
}

export function getDeepPropertyName<T = unknown>(expression: (instance: T) => any) {
    return getPropertyNameInternal(expression, {
        isDeep: true
    });
}
```

Comment: If it's just five lines of code, why don't you post them in your answer? Also currently your answer is basically link-only, it doesn't even show how to use the library or what the library would achieve.

Comment: I assumed that it would be simple enough for people to go to the repo and look at the single `ts` file to get the source code. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done in Javascript/Typescript. There is a [typescript module](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof).

Shamelessly copied from the manual.

```
nameof(console);
nameof(console.log);
nameof(console["warn"]);
```

Transforms to:

```
"console";
"log";
"warn";
```

There are more nice examples in the manual.

The solution for yours question:

```
interface IMyObject {
     myPropertyOther: string;
}
let myObject: IMyObject = {
    myProperty: 'Hello world'
};
console.log(myObject[nameof<IMyObject>((o) => o.myProperty)]);
```