# Typescript correctly rejects wrong type in a function argument if it's a literal but not if it's a variable

Tags: typescript

I have stumbled upon the following issue which to me it looks like Typescript is failing to catch a type error.

In all honesty, it feels a bit weird Typescript would miss this so I suspect it's me who's missing something. I would appreciate if somebody could help me understand.

The following code correctly fails to compile with tsc v3.1.6

```js
type Foo = { bar: string };
function test(x: Foo) { console.log(x); }
test({ bar: 'bar', wrong: 'wrong' });
```

...with the following error:

```
test.ts:3:20 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ bar: string; wrong: 
string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Foo'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'wrong' does 
  not exist in type 'Foo'.

3 test({ bar: 'bar', wrong: 'wrong' });
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, the following code somehow compiles just fine (tsc v3.1.6):

```js
type Foo = { bar: string };
function test(x: Foo) { console.log(x); }
const z = { bar: 'bar', wrong: 'wrong' };
test(z);
```

I would have expected the second snippet to fail with the same error as the first one.

---

## EDIT 1

So I just read again the error message more carefully and it does say "Object literal may…" which implies this rule only applies to literals and not local variables, explaining the issue.

However, I still wonder what's the reason that this rule is not applied to variables as well.

---

## EDIT 2

After reading the comments I realised my question relates to "excess property checks". An alternative title for the question could have been:

*Why do "excess property checks" only apply to object literals?*

Comment: *"I still wonder what's the reason that this rule is not applied to variables as well."* **That** part, I can answer: To allow for subclasses, which do still (after all) have an "is a" relationship with `Foo`. What I can't answer (which is why I didn't post an answer) is why TypeScript restricts object literals in that way. (I could guess, but answers shouldn't be guesses. :-) )

Comment: Where's @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir when you need him? :-)

Comment: Explained in various places, for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143250/how-excess-property-check-helps and https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3755

Comment: Also see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Comment: This might be an intended feature, because by allowing such behaviour, **row type polymorphism** can be achieved. For more info, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092739/what-are-row-types-are-they-algebraic-data-types.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I think I understand better now. It does make sense that "excess property checks" are not applied by default to variables since that would be pretty restrictive (for example like @T.J.Crowder said it would hamper subclassing).

Comment: My only last question would be whether there's any way to achieve something equivalent to an excess property check on variables as arguments to a function call. I have a particular call I would like to protect with such a thing. But maybe I should ask this as a separate question?

Comment: @CarlesTomásMartí - I think so, if you don't find an already-answered version of that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187413/javascript-nameof-object-property) gets you close, but you can't do it in a dynamic loop...